# How can I search for a date using DateTimePicker in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have this sample format of date in my db 
2/26/2014 10:14:04 AM

How can I search for it using a DateTimePicker?

I hope someone would help me. I'm still a newbie.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltransact WHERE date =" & dtpTD.Value.Date & "" 
With cmd 
    .Connection = con 
    .CommandText = sql 
End With 
    da.SelectCommand = cmd 
    da.Fill(dt) 
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: What environment are you in? Are you in Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.net?

Comment: please show the code that you have tried

Comment: What do you mean by "search for it"? - Do you just mean make that the selected date?

Comment: If dtpTD.Text = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a course code.", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Else
                sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltransact WHERE date =" & dtpTD.Value.Date & ""
                With cmd
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandText = sql
                End With
                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                da.Fill(dt)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

Comment: @DLeh I'm using windows forms

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) FYI when someone ask you to show the code, it's better if you edit the post instead.

Comment: @Crono Ok I'll try.. sorry i'm still a newbie here

Comment: NP, I just edited the post for you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try making your query this way instead:

```
Dim myDate As DateTime = dtpTD.Value.Date
sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM tbltransact WHERE YEAR(date) = {0} AND MONTH(date) = {1} AND DAY(date) = {2}", myDate.Year, myDate.Month, myDate.Day)
```

This will give you all the records in tbltransact table for the selected day, regardless of the time.

**UPDATE**

Be aware though that is is considered bad practice to compose your SQL statements this way. Even worse to mix your data layer code with your UI layer code. I suggest that you try and learn how ADO.NET works with parameters so that you can more safely pass values up to your queries.

Comment: Good stuff bud!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `DatePicker` control. This allows you to easily select a date. [Here is an example of using the DatePicker control](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetimepicker)

Comment: I believe the OP got that part figured already, the question seems to be more about how the query should be made.

Comment: He didn't have any details about the query when I wrote this answer.